# How does type coercion for numpy arrays work?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Numpy imported as `np` here:

```
np.array([True, 1, 2]) + np.array([3, 4, False])
```

Which results in:

```
array([4, 5, 2])
```

In this example `boolean` changed to `int`. I assumed it's because of the operation.

```
np.array([True,1,2])
```

Which results in:

```
array(1,1,2)
```

Using a `string` seems it took the priority and changed `int` to `string`.

```
np.array(["True", 1, 2])
```

results in

```
array(['True', '1', '2'], dtype='<U4')

in [4]: np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 'a', True])
Out[4]: 
array(['0', '1', '2', '3', 'a', 'True'], dtype='<U21')`
```

It now seems `string` takes highest priority, and not the number of objects of certain type. Why does it return `dtype='<U4'/'U1'`?

How exactly does this work?

Can I use this property to make change non-zero integers to be `True` and  and zero as `False` or I have to use compare operator?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the dtype? For example, bool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is partially contained in your question. `Boolean` type has implicit conversion to other numeric types since it is just 0 or 1, allowing e.g. arithmetic operations with masks. Numbers are also easily convertible to characters, giving you strings. But the other way around, assigning a `str` value to `int` does not work straight out of the box. That's why when you add a string to your array, it gets immediately generalized to the `str` type. When using `dtype` it returns U#, where # is dictated by the length of your string array, as far as I know, see the official docs [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.scalars.html#arrays-scalars-built-in).
Conversion from numeric arrays to bool works exactly as you specified, if an element is non-zero it returns `True`, otherwise `False`. Example:

```
a=np.array([0.0,1.5,0,1e8,-3])

for b in a:
    if b: print ("hi there")
    else: print ("go away!")
```

Effectively `a` values are treated as [False,True,False,True,True]